# Setting a created timestamp in Firestore with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm adding a document to a firestore collection (`inboxItems`) `onSubmit` of a form.

```
onCreateInboxItem = event => {
  this.props.firebase.inboxItems().add({
    name: this.state.newInboxItemName,
    created: '', // I need a timestamp field here
  })
  this.setState({ name: '' });
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

How do I get the `created` field to be a timestamp field, with current timestamp as a value? It would need to be consistent across users and timezones.

I see `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` mentioned in the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), but at this point the field value isn't set yet. I would like to avoid an extra operation to update the field.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you can't use FieldValue.serverTimestamp().  You just use it as the value of a field at the time you call add().

Comment: "this.props.firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()" doesn't seem to work. Perhaps I'm referencing something wrong here, but I thought FieldValue is only accessible when the field is already set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I use firebase authentication, I initialize firebase with the root App component via the context API. I managed to solve it by adding a helper in my Firebase settings file:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);

    /* Helper */

    this.fieldValue = app.firestore.FieldValue;

    /* Firebase API's */

    this.db = app.firestore();
  }
}
```

And then:

```
this.props.firebase.inboxItems().add({
  created: this.props.firebase.fieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  name: this.state.newInboxItemName,
})
```

Comment: Typically you just make `app` available to your entire app so you don't have to pick the parts out of it that you need. Most JavaScript just assumes that it's a global called `firebase`.

Comment: I use the React Context API so I can provide one instance of firebase at the root component level (needed for authentication, more efficient, and less error-prone). This means that firebase is passed as a prop to child components, that's why the helper is needed.

Comment: @DougStevenson There's a really neat example on https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/, I believe it's the more solid way to use firebase in react.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
created: new Date(),
```

or:

```
created: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
```

Alternatively you could use a cloud function, as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), though that might be overkill.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that create a timestamp based on the local machine time? I would need to make sure it's consistent across users and timezones.

Comment: I believe this still would create a local timestamp, the function seems to just convert your local timestamp to a firebase timestamp. I see something in the docs like "firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()", but at this point the field value isn't set yet.

Comment: You should be able to use `set()` in place of `update()` in the example you're talking about.