# Method for coverting all Firestore Timestamps in a snapshot to JS dates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How would you write a method to convert ***all*** Firestore Timestamps in a snapshot to JavaScript Dates?

For example, a snapshot from a `posts` collection might return a couple Firestore Timestamps (`createdDtTm`, `modifyDtTm`):

```js
[
  { 
    text: 'My new post', 
    uid: 'nzjNp3Q', 
    createDtTm: Timestamp { seconds: 1596239999, nanoseconds: 999000000 },
    modifyDtTm: Timestamp { seconds: 1596239999, nanoseconds: 999000000 },  
  }, 
  { 
    text: 'Another post', 
    uid: 'nzjNp3Q', 
    createDtTm: Timestamp { seconds: 1596239999, nanoseconds: 999000000 },
    modifyDtTm: Timestamp { seconds: 1596239999, nanoseconds: 999000000 },  
  }, 
]
```

Converting the individual dates is simple enough by mapping over the array and using the [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method for each Timestamp (e.g., `createDtTm.toDate()`)

But what is a more generalized approach for converting these two (or any any arbitrary number of) Firestore timestamps, without explicitly specifying the Timestamp fields?

For instance, do Firestore Timestamps have a unique type that could be used for identification?   Would an assumption of naming conventions be required (e.g., field name contains `DtTm`)?  Other?

Previous questions answer how to convert a [single Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247445/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-date-timestamp-to-a-js-date?noredirect=1&lq=1) or a single timestamp in [multiple documents in a snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277859/react-display-a-firestore-timestamp).   But I haven't found a *generalized* approach for converting all Timestamps within a snapshot when *multiple* Timestamps exist.  More specifically, I'm interested in an approach for use within a React `Provider` that would pass JavaScript dates (not Firestore Timestamps) to its `Consumers`,  while also not creating a dependency to update the Provider each time a new Timestamp field is added to the data model / collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any global method for this, but I think its easy to create a function that will analyze snapshot and change it. It's not very complicated. In node.js I have done it like this:

```
function globalToData (snapshot) {
      for (const field in snapshot)
  
    if (snapshot[field] instanceof Firestore.Timestamp) { 
        snapshot[field] = snapshot[field].toDate()
    }
    else if (snapshot[field] instanceof Object) { 
        globalToData (snapshot[field]);
    }
    return snapshot;
};
```

if you get `DocumentSnapshot` as ex. snap you can call it like:

```
globalToData(snap.data())
```

This should convert all Timestamps in all levels of Document snapshot ( I tested to 3rd level of nesting mixed map and array). We do not have your solution, but you can implement this somewhere in the middle of your app.